# Cassandra: what's the read cl of list read-on-write operations?

Tags: cassandra, consistency

Some list operations, like set by index, needs to read the whole list
before update.

So what's the read consistency level of that read? Use the same cl of
the setting for the normal read?

Comment: As far As I know it’s local quorum which is the majority of the total node. if you have 5 nodes then at least 3 node should verify the read or write operation.

Comment: @RamanMishra Quorum depends on the replication factor (RF), not the number of nodes.  So a 5 node cluster with a RF of 3, at least 2 nodes would need to verify the operation.

Comment: I think 5 nodes in which one is leader and others are the replica? Isn’t it? I mean I might be wrong please correct me if it is so.

Answer (score 0):

C* Default Behavior :-

Any read/write operation, including collections like list/set are by default done with consistency=ONE. If you think about it the entire list is available in the same node.

Only time Cassandra uses default higher consistency is for light weight transactions. Here consistency=SERIAL is used.

CL override:-

Application can choose to override this CL during the cluster connection or at query level.

Comment: But it seems that it uses cl set in the session to read list from cluster:
https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/statements/ModificationStatement.java#L398

Comment: Yes what I mentioned is default behavior and you can always override the CL with driver settings or query level.